# Citadels: Price of the poorhouse from Dark City

Tags: citadels

What is the price of the poorhouse from The Dark City expansion? I'm asking, because in my (German) edition the poorhouse doesn't have any coins printed on it, so I suppose this is an error by the publisher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US version, the Poor House costs 5 gold. In European versions, it costs 0 gold. The [general consensus](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/406296/faq-end-all-faqs-work-progress) is that you should play the Poor House with its face value. If your version says 0 cost, that's what you should play it as. If you don't want to do that, make sure you inform everyone about this before the game starts.

It's not clear which publisher is in error, as the creator of the game, Bruno Faidutti, never spoke on the subject.

There are [a lot of inconsistencies](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25602/what-are-the-differences-between-various-versions-of-citadels) between European and US versions of Citadels. Someone [on BGG](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/2223041) once claimed that the 0 cost version is a misprint, but as far as I could tell they had no official source for that information, and it caused a bit of debate.

Comment: Personally I think a 0 cost Poor House is most fitting. After all, why should building a Poor House cost as much as building a Castle?

Comment: The poor house gives you quite some advantage, so building it shouldn't be free. I'll go with the costs of 5 gold, thanks.

Comment: I never experienced any kind of advantage of having a zero cost Poor House. It gets stolen or destroyed quite easily. Even though you'll get a completed city a bit faster, your city will be worth a lot less. But as long as you and your fellow players agree on the cost before the game starts, you're free to choose whichever way you wish to play.

Answer (score 0):

The cost is [5 gold](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Citadels/cards/dc-poor-house-lg.jpg). (Link to Fantasy Flight Poor House card)

Comment: A word of caution, I have seen threads that note that the zero cost is a misprint, but players can choose to play it that way. Nothing official from Bruno Fadutti or Fantasy Flight Games, but I didn't do an extensive search.