# What are the differences between various versions of Citadels

Tags: citadels, edition-comparison

I'm shocked by the amount of rule differences between the US English version of Citadels (by Fantasy Flight) and the various European (non-English) versions.

I'm looking for a complete list of the differences between:

- Citadels (US, Fantasy Flight Games)
- Ohne Furcht und Adel (Germany, Hans im Glueck)
- Machiavelli (Netherlands, 999 Games)
- Citadelles (France, Millennium)

The inconsistency seems to be mostly between US and EU, even though there are so many different publishers. Presumably this is because most EU versions are directly based on the German version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Took some time to compare the rules, but man there's more than I thought. Some are more subtle, others are complete game changers. Here's a complete list (unless I missed any):

- Poor House

  - US: costs 5 gold to build.
  - EU: costs 0 gold to build.
- Removing characters

  - US: First put down the face-down card, then the face-up cards. If needed, replace the king from the face-up cards. The starting player can **not** look at the face-down card.
  - EU: First put down the face-up card, then replace the king if necessary, then play the face-down card. The starting player can look at the face-down card.
- End of turn

  - US: After all the characters have been called, each player returns his character card to the Character Deck.
  - EU: At the end of your turn, place your character card at the center of the table.
- Discarded cards

  - US: Face-down at the bottom of the deck
  - EU: Face-up discard pile
- Character abilities

  - US: Used after performing an action (choosing gold or cards)
  - EU: Can be used before or after performing an action
- Queen ability

  - US: Receives three gold if you are sitting next to the King or the Emperor (eg the person with the King/Emperor card).
  - EU: Receives three gold if she sits next to the player with the wooden king piece.
- Warlord ability (in combination with Bell Tower)

  - US: May not destroy a district in a city that is already completed by having eight districts.
  - EU: May not destroy districts from cities that already has eight districts.
    receive any gold from the Poor House or from their Alchemist ability.
- Emperor ability

  - US: The player who receives the Crown chooses to give you either one gold or one district card from his hand.
  - EU: (no such rule exists)
- Diplomat ability

  - US: Used at end of turn. Can **not** exchange with a completed city.
  - EU: Used at any time during your turn. Can exchange with a completed city.
- Identical districts

  - US: You may not build a district such that you have two identical districts in your city.
  - EU: (no such rule exists)
- Bell Tower

  - US: Bonuses are awarded for seven districts instead of eight.
  - EU: (no such rule exists) bonuses are awarded for eight districts.
- Cemetery

  - US: If you are using the Diplomat you must remove the Cemetery.
  - EU: If you are using the Diplomat, the Cemetery loses its function.
- End of game scoring (in case of tie)

  - US: Most points wins. In case of a tie, only look at points from district cards. *If there's still a tie, whoever has the most gold wins.*
  - EU: Most points wins. In case of a tie, only look at points from district cards.

Everything on the list is based on these documents

- [English](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/f2/e7/f2e74a36-bed7-4a38-aff4-c2e968a1c369/citadels-rules-english.pdf)
- [German](http://www.hans-im-glueck.de/fileadmin/data_archive/Regeln/OFUA_DDL_Regel.pdf)
- [Dutch](http://www.gezelschapsspel.info/sites/default/files/bijlages/Machiavelli%20spelregels.pdf)
- [French](http://www.jeuxavolonte.asso.fr/regles/citadelles_seconde_edition.pdf)

I haven't found any differences between the German, Dutch and French versions, they seem to be mutually consistent.