# Swapping district in completed city

Tags: citadels

Does the Diplomat has the right to swap a district in completed city ?
Warlord cannot destroy a district in a completed city.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25602/what-are-the-differences-between-various-versions-of-citadels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

This is answered in the [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/f2/e7/f2e74a36-bed7-4a38-aff4-c2e968a1c369/citadels-rules-english.pdf) in the description of the Diplomat:

You may not exchange the Keep district, any 
districts in the Bishop’s city, *or any districts in a 
completed city* of eight districts (seven with the 
Bell Tower in play). 
Note: If you are using the 
Diplomat in your game, you must remove the 
Cemetery from the deck since both cannot be 
used together.

It is verified in the [FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Citadels/support/citadels-faq.pdf):

Q: Can the Diplomat exchange one of his districts for 
a district from a completed city of eight districts?
A: No

Comment: This is in the US rules, not in the European rules.